# IE array.flat() Object doesn't support property or method 'flat'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When accessing my website from google chrome everything works fine(also on mobile).
but when trying to access from edge  \ mobile normal browser(not google chrome)
i get

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'flat'
```

trying to access a function .flat of array.

turns out that it dosent exist on the proto at all.
what can i do with it?
the childs array is defined as

```
`let childs = [];`
```

(using react for front end)[image]

Comment: Go to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat and check for the alternatives.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

IE does not support `Array.prototype.flat()`. you can use `reduce` and `concat` as a workaround:

```
childs = childs.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])
```

Comment: The question indicates ECMA is being used – why one must assume Babel or TypeScript is used as transpiler.... transforming spread into [].concat.apply([], childs)

Comment: Do you by any chance have a replacement for value.flatMap((array)?

Comment: @ZolT. flatMap is the same as using map() and then flat(). So you could use map() and replace flat() with wang's answer