# Preact error - Object doesn't support property or method 'flat'

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, preact

In IE11 I'm getting an error caused by Preact. The error is `Object doesn't support property or method 'flat'`. My preact version is `"preact": "^10.3.2"`

Comment: Probably has to do with the `array.flat()` method which isn't supported in IE11. See [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#search=flat). To fix this you could use something like [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your code to older version or include a polyfill like [array-flat-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-flat-polyfill)

Comment: But its strange that Preact itself says that it should be useable with IE11... And it still uses a function which isnt supported?

Comment: Maybe this could be useful. IE did not support that feature. Maybe you could try another option to replace that like a reduce.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/

Comment: Agree with theblackgigant,you could try to use the [Array Flat Polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-flat-polyfill) or [use reduce and concat as a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53022556/).`But its strange that Preact itself says that it should be useable with IE11...`From the [Preact doc](https://preactjs.com/guide/v10/getting-started/#best-practices-powered-by-preact-cli), the Preact CLI 's built on standard tooling projects like Webpack, Babel and PostCSS. so, perhaps it already adds the babel polyfill (without the flat method),so,you have to add the flat polyfill.

Comment: Yes implementing `Array flat polyfill` seems to do the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used [Array Flat polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/array-flat-polyfill) to fix the issue.