# How to concat arrays alternatively every 2 items? JS

Tags: javascript

**I have:**

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
```

I got the concat of arrays working, but only one at a time:

```
var alternatingArrayResult = [array1, array2].reduce(function (r, a) {
                        return a.forEach(function (a, i) {
                            return (r[i] = r[i] || []).push(a);
                        }), r;
                    }, []).reduce(function (a, b) {
                        return a.concat(b);
                    });

// => alternatingArrayResult = [1, 'a', 2, 'b', 3, 'c', 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```

I want to add two items from array 1, then one from array 2 - and so on.

**Desired output:**

```
result = [1, 2, 'a', 3, 4, 'b', 5, 6, 'c', 7, 8, 9];
```

```js
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
var array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
var alternatingResultArray = [array1, array2].reduce(function (r, a) {
                    return a.forEach(function (a, i) {
                        return (r[i] = r[i] || []).push(a);
                    }), r;
                }, []).reduce(function (a, b) {
                    return a.concat(b);
                });
                    
console.log(alternatingResultArray);
```

Comment: What's the logic behind the pattern? Will the letters always be separated by two numbers? What if there are two letters, but only one number?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get a lenght and iterate the parts for pushing.

```js
const
    array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    result = [];

for (i = 0, l = Math.max(Math.ceil(array1.length / 2), array2.length); i < l; i++) {
    result.push(
        ...array1.slice(i * 2, (i + 1) * 2),
        ...array2.slice(i, i + 1),
    );
}

console.log(...result);
```

A more abstact version with size of the wanted subarrays.

```js
const
    array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
    array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    data = [array1, array2],
    sizes = [2, 1]
    result = [];

for (i = 0, l = Math.max(...data.map(({ length }, i) => Math.ceil(length / sizes[i]))); i < l; i++) {
    data.forEach((a, j) => result.push(...a.slice(i * sizes[j], (i + 1) * sizes[j])));
}

console.log(...result);
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work, but I'm trying to figure out how to make this IE11 friendly - the spread operator is not okay for this, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: you yoult take `Array.prototype.push.apply(result, array1.slice(i * 2, (i + 1) * 2))` and for the second array as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.map` with a `thisArg` for the desired result ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)).

> thisArg (Optional) Value to use as this when executing callback.

```js
let array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
let array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
let arrayConcatted = array1
  .flatMap( function(v, i) {
  //        ^ not arrow to keep thisArg in scope
    const arr2Value = i && i % 2 === 0 && this.length && this.shift();
    return arr2Value ? [arr2Value, v] : v;
  }, array2.slice())
  // ^ 'this', a copy of array2

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayConcatted));

// IE
var arrConcatIE = [];
var arr2Clone = array2.slice();
for (var i=0; i < array1.length; i +=1) {
    const arr2Value = i && i % 2 === 0 && arr2Clone.length && arr2Clone.shift();
    if (arr2Value) {
      arrConcatIE.push(arr2Value);
    }
    arrConcatIE.push(array1[i]);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrConcatIE));
```

Comment: You can directly use `flatMap`.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work, but I'm trying to figure out how to make this IE11 friendly - `.flat()` is not okay for this. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53022556/ie-array-flat-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-flat) seemed appropriate, but I can't seem to make it work with your code. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Added an IE-compatible solution.